# Different full screen backgrounds with ACF

Tags: wordpress, background, fullscreen, advanced-custom-fields

In a cusotm post type I'm having 5 different images which can defined by an advanced custom field. With the following code I have defined the background of my #inner-header as the first image:

```
<?php $background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' ); ?>

    <style>
    #inner-header {
        background-image: url('<?php echo $background[0]; ?>');
    }
    </style>
```

Now I'd like to use arrows in my page to switch the background of the different images I have defined.

Comment: please show the code you have so far to do this. or use [backstrech](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

Comment: I have used to code above, because before I only intended to use a single background image. I don't have more than this.